# Should the neurons in a neural network be asynchronous?

Tags: machine-learning, erlang, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am designing a neural network and am trying to determine if I should write it in such a way that each neuron is its own 'process' in Erlang, or if I should just go with C++ and run a network in one thread (I would still use all my cores by running an instance of each network in its own thread).

Is there a good reason to give up the speed of C++ for the asynchronous neurons that Erlang offers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. An artificial neural network is essentially represented by the weight of the connections between nodes. The nodes themselves don't exist in isolation; their values are only calculated (at least in feed-forward networks) through the forward-propagation algorithm, when it is given input.

The backpropagation algorithm for updating weights is definitely parallelizable, but that doesn't seem to be what you're describing.

Comment: This belongs more to a comment instead to an answer. Tips to create great answers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/answering

Comment: In a book I'm reading, the network consists of a set of neurons, each an Erlang process that send signals to other neurons. The output is calculated not by an external algorithm, but as the input propagates through the network. (See Handbook of Neuroevolution Through Erlang)

Comment: @Joe Yes, ***Neuroevolution Through Erlang*** is a great book, however, the main missing point is, that Gene Sher has put into these **biologically inspired TWEANN sort of ANN** but which you forgot to mention, is their ability to evolve in a Topology "dimension", besides the Weight-based penalty minimiser. This is an important feature of Gene Sher's architecture.

Answer (score 1):

The usefulness of having neurons in a Neural Network (NN), is to have a multi-dimension matrix which coefficients you want to handle ( to train them, to change them, to adapt them little by little, so as they fit well to the problem you want to solve). On this matrix you can apply numerical methods (proven and efficient) so as to find an acceptable solution, in an acceptable time.

IMHO, with NN (namely with back-propagation training method), the goal is to have a matrix which is efficient both at run-time/predict-time, and at training time.

I don't grasp the point of having asynchronous neurons. What would it offers ? what issue would it solve ?

Maybe you could explain clearly what problem you would solve putting them asynchronous ?

I am indeed inverting your question: what do you want to gain with asynchronicity regarding traditional NN techniques ?

Comment: Upon further research, it appears that some main benefits are
A) Being able to scale the system to any size (a billion neurons can't run on my laptop)
B) Having no synchronization/heartbeat to guide the network (ex. a spiking neural network)

Comment: okay, but the **HUGE** risk of having billions of neurons is that it will simply overfit your training data, and won't generalize over your domain - without even taking into account the time to train such model. I don't see what you mean by synchronization/heartbeat.  I'm starting to wonder if indeed you are trying to model a biological Neural Network - which is completely different from a Machine-Learning / Artifical-Intelligence Neural Network.

Comment: The first paragraph is completely wrong or badly written: The usefulness of a NN shall be the fact that you can use some neat mathematical tricks to implement them? You're sure that's what you want to say? I'd say they're useful because they are good function approximators.

Comment: Yep, I insist, that's what I really wanted to say. I was namely speaking about the **BackPropagation** technique for training the NN fastly for example. Once the NN has been trained, then yes you get the function approximator you refer to (what I call the predict-phase), and of course this is where the NN is useful to produce results ;-) But if the NN could not be trained in a reasonable time, then they would not be useful *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend upon your use case: the neural network computational model and your execution environment.  Here is a recent paper (2014) by Plotnikova et al, that uses "Erlang and platform Erlang/OTP with predefined base implementation of actor model functions" and a new model developed by the authors that they describe as “one neuron—one process” using "Gravitation Search Algorithm" for training:

http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-319-06764-3_52

To briefly cite their abstract, "The paper develops asynchronous distributed modification of this algorithm and presents the results of experiments. The proposed architecture shows the performance increase for distributed systems with different environment parameters (high-performance cluster and local network with a slow interconnection bus)."

Also, most other answers here reference a computational model that uses matrix operations for the base of training and simulation, for which the authors of this paper compare by saying, "this case neural network model [ie matrix operations based] becomes fully mathematical and its original nature (from neural networks biological prototypes) gets lost"

The tests were run on three types of systems;

1. IBM cluster is represented as 15 virtual machines.
2. Distributed system deployed to the local network is represented as 15 physical machines.
3. Hybrid system is based on the system 2 but each physical machine has four processor cores.

They provide the following concrete results, "The presented results evidence a good distribution ability of gravitation search, especially for large networks (801 and more neurons). Acceleration depends on the node count almost linearly. If we use 15 nodes we can get about eight times acceleration of the training process."

Finally, they conclude regarding their model, "The model includes three abstraction levels: NNET, MLP and NEURON. Such architecture allows encapsulating some general features on general levels and some specific for the considered neural networks features on special levels. Asynchronous message passing between levels allow to differentiate synchronous and asynchronous parts of training and simulation algorithms and, as a result, to improve the use of resources."

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you are after.

**2nd Generation** of Neural Networks are synchronous. They perform computations on an input-output basis without a delay, and can be trained either through reinforcement or back-propagation. This is the prevailing type of ANN at the moment and the easiest to get started with if you are trying to solve a problem via machine learning, lots of literature and examples available.

**3rd Generation** of Neural Networks (so-called "[Spiking Neural Networks](https://towardsdatascience.com/spiking-neural-networks-the-next-generation-of-machine-learning-84e167f4eb2b)") are asynchronous. Signals propagate internally through the network as a chain-reaction of spiking events, and can create [interesting patterns and oscillations depending on the shape of the network](https://desalasworks.com/article/asynchronous-neural-networks-in-javascript/). While they model biological brains more closely they are also [harder to make use of in a practical setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiking_neural_network#Applications).

Answer (score 0):

I think that async computation for NNs might prove beneficial for the (recognition) performance. In fact, the result might be similar (maybe less pronounced) to using [dropout](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/srivastava14a.old/source/srivastava14a.pdf).

But a straight-forward implementation of async NNs would be much slower, because for synchronous NNs you can use linear algebra libraries, which make good use of vectorization or GPUs.